# How insert array values with foreach in opencart?

Tags: foreach, opencart

My case similar with this [Insert array values with foreach using codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340898/insert-array-values-with-foreach-using-codeigniter) (user input by dynamically adding and removing fields).

But it's CI, I trying in open cart, so I build function insert and passing value(in array) and performs for each in model.

What I want insert is product this for code Controller :

```
// check request and store to array
if(isset($this->request->get['product']))
{ 
    $product = $this->request->get['product'];
    $product2 = array();
    foreach($product as $p)
    {
        $product2[] = $p;
    }
}
else 
{
    $product = null;
}


// This for function insert 
public function insert()
{
    $this->language->load('item/item');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title')); 

    $this->load->model('item/item');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) 
    {
        $this->model_item_item->insert_detail($this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('item/item', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }
}
```

This is for Model :

```
public function insert_detail($product2)
{
    foreach($product2 as $detail)
    {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product_detail SET product_id = '". $this->db->escape($detail['product']) . "'");
    }
}
```

This for View :

```
    <?php echo $header; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
  <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($success) { ?>
  <div class="success"><?php echo $success; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1><img src="view/image/product.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <div class="buttons"><a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_save; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_cancel; ?></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <table class="form">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_head; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="head_text_field" value="" placeholder="Input Head Text" size="40"/>
                <?php if ($error_head) { ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_head; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_title; ?></td>
            <td><textarea name="title_text_field" placeholder="Input Title Text" style="width:230px;"/></textarea>
                <?php if ($error_title) { ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_title; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_max_item; ?></td>
            <td>
                <select name="max" id="maxitem">
                <?php
                for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
                {
                    if($i == 1)
                        echo "<option selected='selected' value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                    else
                        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry_product; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product" name="product" value="" placeholder="Input Product" size="40"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="ADD" value="Add Item"></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" id="RESET" value="Reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" id="tblname" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    Name Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    DELETE
                </td>
            <tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody align="center">
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This for Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {       
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        value: item.product_id
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }, 
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('input[name=\'product\']').val(ui.item.label);

        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
});

//--></script>
<Script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item = 1;
    var isAllowed   = 3;
    var isSet       = 0;
    $('#ADD').click(function(){
        var maxitem = parseInt($("#maxitem").val(), 10); //from max item in html
        var iCount = 0;
        if($('#product').val()){  // check input product
            if( item <= maxitem )
            {
                iCount = $('#tblname tbody tr').length + 1;
                szTr = "<tr><td>";
                szTr = szTr + iCount + "</td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "<td>" +$('#product').val() +"</td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "<td><input type='button' class='DEL' value='DELETE'></td>";
                szTr = szTr +   "</tr>";                     
                $('#tblname tbody').append(szTr);
                item +=1;
                isSet = 1;
                restFormOpts();
            }
            else
            {
                alert ("Max Limit !!!");
            }
        }else{alert('Enter Product !!! ');}
    });

    // for delete row
    $('body').on('click','#RESET', function() {
        item        = 1;
        isAllowed   = 3;
        isSet       = 0;
        $("#maxitem").attr("disabled",false);
        $('.DEL').parents('tr').remove();
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'input.DEL', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();  
        item -= 1;
    });

    function restFormOpts()
    {
        if(isSet === isAllowed) {
            $("#ADD").attr("disabled",true);
            $("#maxitem").attr("disabled",false);
        }
        else {
            $("#ADD").attr("disabled",false);
            $("#maxitem").attr("disabled",true);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This code works to enter into the database , but no contents?
Where i did mistake?

Comment: Open Cart and Codeigniter code are different. The may look they same though.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 ow sorry as I recall only enter foreach and opencart only.

Comment: `INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product_detail SET product_id = '". $this->db->escape($detail['product']) . "'` does not generate a valid mysql insert statement.

Comment: @Fabricator sorry can you help me with write the correct code?

Comment: sure. what fields are in `show_product_detail` table, and what's in `$detail`?

Comment: @Fabricator fields show_product_detail is only 2 , 1 for PK(AI) and 1 for "product_id" , $detail is $product2 it's product_id but in array $product2

Comment: i mean what columns are in `show_product_detail` table, and what keys are in `$product2`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101963/discussion-between-vilthering-and-fabricator).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) statement:

```
$this->db->query("
    INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product_detail 
    (show_product_detail) 
    values ('". $this->db->escape($detail['product']) . "'");
```

Comment: it's not work the query not run when i try it, its stuck in insert, if correct should be back to admin/item/item.php

Comment: i'm sorry. i'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

You are putting an array in `product_id` field.

First you need to change `product_id` field type `int` to `text` and

**Check with following code**

```
public function insert_detail($product2)
{
    foreach($product2 as $detail)
    {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "show_product_detail SET product_id = '". $this->db->escape(json_encode($detail)) . "'");
    }
}
```